# bash: capture lines with the same specific number of characters from the beginning

Tags: bash, awk, grep, character, capture

I want to capture lines which have the same beginning on their first nth characters and only output one of those lines no matter what comes after the first nth character.
If the line has less than nth chars, then send it to output as it is.

I tried grep to capture the first specific number of chars but it removes the rest!

`cat myfile.txt | grep -o -P '^{0,41}'`
or
`cat myfile.txt | grep -o -P '.{0,0}http.{0,41}'`

**Here I have a file and I want to capture lines which are the same in their first 41 characters and only show one of them:**

```
https://example.com/first/second/blahblah/?alsda=asldfaalafowiorie
https://example.com/first/second/blahblah/?oriwo=asldkjalkdjf2kasd
https://example.com/first/second/blahblah/some/more/dir
https://example.com/another/one
https://example.com/third/fourth/something/?cldl=aosijfoiret
https://example.com/third/fourth/something/?cldl=5145652
https://example.com/third/fourth/something/?hfdg=156569&wuew=8428
https://example.com/first/second/blahblah/
```

**Desired output**

```
https://example.com/first/second/blahblah/?alsda=asldfaalafowiorie
https://example.com/another/one
https://example.com/third/fourth/something/?cldl=aosijfoiret
```

Thanks.

Comment: `If the line has less than nth chars, then send it to output as it is` even if it is repreated?

Comment: It would be good if there is a way to make them unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '!seen[substr($0,1,41)]++' file
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.
What resource do you recommend for learning awk? any specific website or book?

Answer (score 0):

Just the usual `sort&uniq` pair.

```
sort file | uniq -w40
```

You might want to do something along `sort -s -k1.1,1.40 file` to have it stable sorted.

---

> nly output one of those lines no matter what comes after the first nth character. If the line has less than nth chars, then send it to output as it is.

For anything else, there is almighty awk.

```
awk -v N=41 '
   # Put lines longer then 41 in associative array, if not there already
   length($0) >= N { i = substr($0,1,N); if (!(i in a)) a[i] = $0 }
   # output lines shorter then 41
   length($0) < N {print}
   # output the array
   END{ for (i in a) print a[i] } ' file
```

Comment: It works as I want, but @rowboat 's solution is simpler and shorter. Thank you.